How to understand the Landsat457 cloud removal code recommended by GEE
What does the cloud removal code recommended by GEE mean?
// This example demonstrates the use of the Landsat 4, 5, 7 Collection 2,
// Level 2 QA_PIXEL band (CFMask) to mask unwanted pixels.

function maskL457sr(image) {
  // Bit 0 - Fill
  // Bit 1 - Dilated Cloud
  // Bit 2 - Unused
  // Bit 3 - Cloud
  // Bit 4 - Cloud Shadow
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);//***what dose this mean?***

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);//***What is the purpose of this step?***
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);//***What is the purpose of this step?***

  // Replace the original bands with the scaled ones and apply the masks.
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
      .addBands(thermalBand, null, true)
      .updateMask(qaMask)
      .updateMask(saturationMask);
}

// Map the function over one year of data.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
                     .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2011-01-01')
                     .map(maskL457sr);

var composite = collection.median();

// Display the results.
Map.setCenter(-4.52, 40.29, 7);  // Iberian Peninsula
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'], min: 0, max: 0.3});

If I use the code bellow, what's the problem of it?
function CloudMask(image){
  var CloudShadow = (1<<3);
  var Cloud = (1<<4);
  var qa = image.select("QA_PIXEL");
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(CloudShadow).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(Cloud).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}


Thank you very much @Spacedman

Scale factor and offset to convert from Unsigned 16-bit integer to floating point reflectance and Radiometric Saturation

@user2856, thank you for answering my question first.
I have seen "L2SP guide", but I can't understand still.
